# Qual a melhor prática para pastas vazias no .gitignore

Tags: git, versionamento

Algumas pessoas me disseram que o correto é criar um arquivo vazio e colocar dentro de cada pasta e setar um `.gitignore` assim:

```
/pasta/subpasta/*
!/pasta/subpasta/.arquivovazio
```

E outras pessoas me falaram para criar um arquivo .gitignore dentro de cada pasta com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
# ignorar todos
*
# exceto o .gitignore
!.gitignore
```

Criar um único arquivo `.gitignore` ou um em cada pasta? Qual a melhor alternativa?

Lembrando que as duas formas foram testadas e funcionaram.

Comment: Acho que a resposta beira potencialmente a questão de opiniões pessoais. A minha resposta é uma, por isso coloco como comentário e não como resposta. Eu prefiro criar um único arquivo e ficar mantendo só ele do que ficar criando um arquivo pra cada pasta que eu criar. Diminui a quantidade de arquivos para as quais tanto eu quanto o Git temos que ficar dando atenção.

Comment: Legal, achei interessante esse ponto de vista.. mas ai entra a questão, qual a diferença entre criar um arquivo vazio em cada pasta ou colocar um gitignore? muda alguma coisa pro git? porque fazendo da forma que você falou eu precisaria criar um arquivo vazio igual em cada pasta, senão ela não versiona..

Comment: Nunca pensei nisso, mas também nunca precisei criar um projeto com diretórios vazios. Não vejo a necessidade, talvez por nunca ter tido esse requisito. Se eu realmente precisasse de diretórios que não vão conter nada, eu deixaria a aplicação criá-los conforme a necessidade e em tempo de uso, mas não manteria os diretórios no repositório.

Comment: Sim, concordo contigo mas no meu caso hoje tenho alguns sites que precisam, por exemplo em alguns uso o smarty e ele gera os arquivos dentro do templates_c e não tenho como cria-la pela aplicação, então preciso ter ela no controle de versão.. e tem alguns provedores, por exemplo a kinghost que não me deixa criar pastas, dar permissões a elas através do php, então preciso ter as pastas das imagens que o cliente cadastra no controle de versão vazias para não versionar imagens de testes por exemplo

Comment: Uma solução possível seria usar um arquivo .gitpeak nos diretórios vazios. 
Essa [pergunta do SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229996) ajudará a entender melhor.

Comment: Não conheço o gitpeak, vou dar uma olhada.. Obrigado pela dica

Comment: Se sua aplicação é php, coloca um index.php em vez de um arquivo oculto ou algo do gênero. Dessa forma você adiciona uma singela camada de segurança na sua aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

Depende do que você quer fazer:

- Se você quer que as pastas sejam versionadas, mesmo vazias, crie-as e coloque um arquivo `.gitkeep`, vazio, nelas;
- Se você não precisa versionar as pastas (mas não quer comitá-las caso elas venham a ser criadas), basta adicionar o caminho das pastas no arquivo `.gitignore` na raiz do projeto.

Comment: beleza.. você e o segundo que me fala do .gitkeep, vou tentar implementar.. obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Olha só pessoal, dei uma pesquisada, analisada e cheguei a conclusão que cada situação é única e para minha o melhor foi criar um arquivo .gitignore dentro de cada pasta que eu quero manter vazia e definir para o .gitignore ignorar todos os arquivos menos ele. Porque tenho pastas que ficam vazias mas também tenho pastas que são ocupadas por arquivos que não quero versionar, como imagens de testes dos sites, então pra mim, o melhor foi criar um arquivo .gitignore dentro de cada pasta que quero deixar versionada e vazia. Obrigado pela ajuda de todos.